# Create mean value plot without missing values count to total

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using a dataframe with missing values:

```
structure(list(id = c("id1", "test", "rew", "ewt"), total_frq_1 = c(54, 87, 10, 36), total_frq_2 = c(45, 24, 202, 43), total_frq_3 = c(24, NA, 25, 8), total_frq_4 = c(36, NA, 104, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

How is is possible to create a bar plot with the mean for every column, excluding the id column, but without filling the missing values with 0 but leaving out the row with missing values example for `total_frq_3 24+25+8 = 57/3 = 19`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colMeans` function and pass it the appropriate argument to ignore NA.

```
library(ggplot2)
xy <- structure(list(id = c("id1", "test", "rew", "ewt"), 
total_frq_1 = c(54, 87, 10, 36), total_frq_2 = c(45, 24, 202, 43), total_frq_3 = c(24, NA, 25, 8), 
total_frq_4 = c(36, NA, 104, NA)), 
row.names = c(NA, 4L), 
class = "data.frame")

xy.means <- colMeans(x = xy[, 2:ncol(xy)], na.rm = TRUE)
xy.means <- as.data.frame(xy.means)
xy.means$total <- rownames(xy.means)

ggplot(xy.means, aes(x = total, y = xy.means)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Or just use base image graphic

```
barplot(height = colMeans(x = xy[, 2:ncol(xy)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: @ErikBrole sure, check the reference of [coord_flip](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_flip.html).